# Extract DN (Distinguished Names) from a X.509 certificate using iOS API

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, x509

I need to extract the DN (Distinguished Names) from a X.509 certificate using iOS native API. Without using any 3rd party libraries like OpenSSL.

I need to extract it as a string with the following format, as defined by X.509 standard:

```
CN=John Smith, OU=Test, O=IBM, C=GB
```

I found [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/2799309-seccertificatecopynormalizedsubj?language=objc) which seems to return what I'm looking for, according to its signature:

```
CFDataRef SecCertificateCopyNormalizedSubjectSequence(SecCertificateRef certificate);
```

This method returns a DER encoded sequence. The method header comment says:

> The subject is a sequence in the format used by SecItemCopyMatching.
>   The content returned is a DER-encoded X.509 distinguished name. For a
>   display version of the subject, call SecCertificateCopyValues.

The issue is that **SecCertificateCopyValues** method is available for macOS only.

Is there any alternative way to extract the string representation of the DER encoded values from the returned data using iOS available API?